# php Code return blank page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am testing some code for a local wordpress site and am editing the theme's functions.php file. As i was writing the below code, it just return a blank site. Anyone can enlighten me? i tried turning on error reporting on WAMP, but nothing appears.

```
global $woocommerce;
$box_found = false;
$voucher_found = false;
$other_products_found = false;

//start of the loop that fetches the cart items
foreach($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $_product = $values['data'];
    $terms = get_the_terms( $_product->id, 'product_cat' );

    // second level loop search, in case some items have several categories
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $_categoryid = $term->term_id;
    }

    //check if BOX product category is in card
    if ( $_categoryid === 103 ) {
        //category is in cart!
        $box_found = true;
    }

    //check if VOUCHER product category is in card
    if ( $_categoryid === 106 ) {
        //category is in cart!
        $voucher_found = true;
    }

    //check if VOUCHER product category is in card
    if (( $_categoryid !== 103 )||($_categoryid !== 106 )) {
        //category is in cart!
        $other_products_found = true;
    }
}
```

However, when i enclose the entire code in a function, then the webpage returns to normal.

Comment: Do you have PHP errors turned on?

Comment: In general blank page means a syntax error,check your brackets etc.Do you have the php tags?

Comment: yes i have php tags and php error log is turned on, but there's nothing inside that correspond to the error timing

Comment: This code must be interacting with other code following it in a _bad_ way. Enclosing it in a `function` that you don't later call is like commenting it, though if it was a syntax error commenting it would fix that too.